# How to test a Parallel Payments IPN Listener

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi I'm trying to find out how to test my IPN Listener for an Adaptive Payments API Parallel Payment scenario.

specifically: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator from there I can't seem to select Pay Message as a type.

I've coded my IPN Listener to expect these parameters ( namely, need pay_key and transaction receiver )

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id0991G0M005Z

Is there a way to test my listener code?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPN Simulator is limited. It doesn't allow you to simulate every type of transaction.

You can still test this though. You just need to submit a Parallel Payment API call from a Sandbox Seller account. You don't need to create an application to use in the Sandbox. Every Seller account has the proper permission for Adaptive Payments and there is an APP-ID anyone can use in the Sandbox - `APP-80W284485P519543T`

Comment: Thanks!  just to add to this, I've been using the service at requestb.in ( http://requestb.in ) as my beta and local environments aren't reachable by Paypal's IPN message sender.  it works great.  I have been able to fake the message being sent by taking what Paypal sends there and sending the raw post body to the PPIPNListener class ( PHP ) from https://packagist.org/packages/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php